# How are the View's @Model, ViewDataDictionary, ViewData and ViewBag related with each other?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

What are the relationships between those (if there is any)?

I know that ViewBag can access ViewData, except that ViewBag is of type Dynamic.

In addition, ViewData is of type ViewDataDictionary.

Can anyone elaborate more on these, **especially** the relationship between the `ViewData` and a view's `Model` `@model` if there is one?

**UPDATE:**

I just realized after doing some breakpointing and debugging that there is no relationship between a View's `Model` property (razor's `@model`) and its `ViewData.`

**UPDATE:**

Actually, I take that back. A View's Model is actually part of `ViewData` located in its `ViewData.Model`

Now I'm just wondering about ViewData and ViewBag?

Comment: Might be interested in [this](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Difference-Between-ViewBag-and-ViewData-in-MVC-3.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single difference is that ViewBag uses the dynamic feature. As [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) said:

> It achieves the same goal as viewdata and should be avoided in favor
>   of using strongly typed view models (the same way as viewdata should
>   be avoided).

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705426/whats-the-difference-between-viewdata-and-viewbag) and at [dtryon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781707/dtryon)'s [link](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Difference-Between-ViewBag-and-ViewData-in-MVC-3.aspx) posted below your question.