# MVC3 actionlink attaches ID to Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I have a an object view with data and a button on that view. The user can review the object info and click the button to go to a new view form whee he can enter info to create an item. My challenge is this, how would I attach the ID of the object on the previous view to associate it with and attach to the information they create and submit?

Comment: can you show some code ? it will be helpful to solve the problem

Comment: I'm sending from my iPad right now so notat the moment. Do u know of a good solution to fit this conceptually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add","AddNotes","Object",new {@id=5},null)
```

This will create an a tag with querystring `?id=5`. (You may replace the hardcoded 5 with the dynamic value in your view)

Have a property to keep this value for your `ViewModel/Model` for the create form.

```
public class CreateNoteViewModel
{
  public int ParentId { set;get;}
  public string Note { set;get;}
  //Other properties also
}
```

Read this in your GET `action` method which creates the second view and set the value of that property of the ViewModel/Model.

```
public ActionResult AddNotes(int id)
{
  var model=new CreateNoteViewModel();
  model.ParentId=id;
  return View(model);
}
```

And in your strongly typed view, Keep this value inside a hidden variable.

```
@model CreateNoteViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Model.Note)
 @Html.HiddenFor(Model.ParentId)
 <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now in your `HttpPost` action , you can get the Object Id from your POSTED model's ParentId property

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNotes(CreateNoteViewModel model)
{
 if(ModelState.IsValid()
 {
   //check for model.ParentId here
   // Save and redirect
 }
 return View(model); 
}
```

Comment: I am working on this solution right now. I will thank you by marking as answer if I succeed. Thanks for the code. ( :

Comment: does it matter whether it's set;get; or get;set;. I have get;set;

Comment: @HelloJonnyOh: that order does not matter.

Comment: Is this best practice over using ViewData and / or Session?

Comment: Use ViewModels wherever possible over ViewData and Session. This keeps your code strongly typed and clean. ViewData is dynamic and using that so much produces unmanagable ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use hidden input & viewdata, PSEUDOCODE.  ***NOTE*** you may have to use strings with view data and convert back to your id in your controller.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023313/1166147) for a basic explanation of ViewData/ViewBag (and cons).

You'll need to pass the data to the view from the first action (Controller)
The Controller base class has a "ViewData" dictionary property that can be used to populate data that you want to pass to a View.  You add objects into the ViewData dictionary using a key/value pattern.

controller

```
 public ActionResult yourfirstaction()
      {
            //assign and pass the key/value to the view using viewdata
            ViewData["somethingid"] = ActualPropertyId;
```

in view - get the value use it with the hidden input to pass back to next controller to render next view

```
 <input type="hidden" name="somethingid" value='@ViewData["somethingid"]' id="somethingid" />
```

controller

```
  public ActionResult yournextaction(string somethingid)
      {
            //use the id
            int ActualPropertyId =  Convert.ToInt32(somethingid);
```

Comment: Where would I place the hidden input? I assume the page where the user is coming from...

Comment: where should the ACTUAL name of my property that I want to pass go? Can you edit your pseudocode and replace with "ActualPropertyId"?