# how to show only first object from list which have assigned to viewbag in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, foreach, viewbag

I have assigned a list to `ViewBag` as below.

[image]

this is the code ...

```
var cer = tac.getAwards(hotelLocID);
            List<Certificates> allcertificates = new List<Certificates>();
            foreach (var items in cer)
            {
                allcertificates.Add(new Certificates
                {
                    certifyimageurllarge = items.awardimage.largeimage,
                    certifyimageurlsmall = items.awardimage.smallimage,
                    certifyimageurltiny = items.awardimage.tinyimage,
                    awardedyear = items.year,
                    awardtype = items.awardtype
                });
            }


            ViewBag.certificates = allcertificates;
```

in here `allcertificates` list count is 2.but I want to show only first one in the `View`.this is my view

```
@foreach(var items in @ViewBag.certificates)
                    {
                    <div class="row" style="padding-left:3%;">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><img class="img img-responsive" src="@items.certifyimageurltiny" /></div><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8" style="margin-left:-6%;padding-top:2%;">@items.awardtype | @items.awardedyear</div>
                    </div>
                    }
```

How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of foreach:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-left:3%;">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
       <img class="img img-responsive" src="@ViewBag.certificates[0].certifyimageurltiny"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8" style="margin-left:-6%;padding-top:2%;">
       @ViewBag.certificates[0].awardtype | @ViewBag.certificates[0].awardedyear
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A minimal change would be to simply add a line with `break;` just above the closing `}`.

Answer (score 0):

job done in `View` side like this

```
 <div class="row" style="padding-left:3%;">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><img class="img img-responsive" src="@ViewBag.certificates[0].certifyimageurltiny" /></div><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8" style="margin-left:-6%;padding-top:2%;">@ViewBag.certificates[0].awardtype | @ViewBag.certificates[0].awardedyear</div>
                    </div>
```

this link : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508961/how-to-loop-through-two-viewbag-items-on-view-pages-in-mvc-4-0) helped me lot.thanx everyone who supprted me.