# How does ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC work behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, viewbag

I am reading a book on ASP.NET MVC and I'm wondering how the following example works:

### Example #1

#### Controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.MyProperty = 5;

        return View();
    }
}
```

#### View

```
<h1>@ViewBag.MyProperty</h1>
```

Now I understand that `ViewBag` is a dynamic object, so that's how you can set the property (though I don't know much about dynamic objects, never worked with them.) But how does the view get the specific instance of the `ViewBag` from the controller, even though we don't pass anything directly?

I thought that the `ViewBag` could be a `public` `static` object, but then any change to it would be global and it wouldn't be specific to a view instance.

Could you elaborate as to how this works behind the scenes?

### Example #2

#### Controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.MyProperty = 5;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        ViewBag.MyProperty = 6;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Now let's say the `Index` method is called first, and then the `Index2`. In the end the value of `ViewBag.MyProperty` will end up as 6 (the value from `Index2`). I feel that it is not a good thing to do, but at the same time I feel that I'm thinking in desktop development terms. Maybe it doesn't matter when used with ASP.NET MVC, as the web is stateless. **Is this the case?**

Comment: I would imagine that the `ViewBag` object is simply instantiated with the controller object as an instance property (not `static`).

Comment: You can see it's actually a member of the controller: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: So if there are two methods returning different views set the same property on the `ViewBag` instance, it can affect each other? Wouldn't that cause a problem? I feel that I'm still thinking in desktop development though.

Comment: The controller is instantiated when `Index()` is called, and disposed after `return View();` is executed.  So `ViewBag` goes out of scope once the entire request is completed.  That's why the `ViewBag` properties do not persist across requests.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, alright then. It makes sense now. I didn't know what was instantiated when. As I said, still thinking in desktop development way. Could you write these as an answer, I will choose it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I would, but it's unclear from the MSDN page that @dbaseman linked what is actually stored in that `object` property.  I suspect that it is an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

Comment: @hattenn WebForms is a web framework that's *close* to desktop development. MVC, however, is way much different. It's much more the web paradigm. So, trying to understand MVC tools (such as the ViewBag) making a parallel to desktop will always lead you to confusing conclusions (or questions).

Comment: I remember reading it was an `ExpandObject` couple minutes ago somewhere, let me see.

Comment: Wow, `ExpandoObject` is cool.  It implements `IEnumerable`, so all of the Linq methods work on it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14985891/494094; Aniket says that it is an `ExpandObject`, but unfortunately he didn't cite his resource. @AndreCalil, you are right that it is completely different than desktop development. I'm just trying to wrap my mind around it and change my mindset.

Comment: You can browse the classes definition from VS: `Controller` inherits `ControllerBase` that has the `public dynamic ViewBag { get; }` property

Comment: @RobertHarvey I believe that this question deserves an wiki answer =)

Comment: There are so many things that works like magic behind the scenes of ASP.NET MVC though, it's not just trying to understand the way web works. So many conventions and magic stuff. It looks great but nothing that I'm used to.

Comment: @hattenn I had this feeling when I started on ASP.NET MVC too, and I hate it. If I ask myself "how does this work?" and I can't give a reasonable answer, I'll look for it. Keep using MVC and you'll notice that there's no magic, it's all conventions (which you have to discover, somtimes).

Comment: @AndreCalil, yeah sure, but it looks like magic until you read it and understand how it is implemented :) It's kind of cool though, I like it. It's just a bit tiring as I keep asking "Wait a minute, how the hell would that work?" all the time.

Comment: @hattenn While learning ASP.NET MVC, http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ helped me a lot. Check it out!

Comment: @AndreCalil, thanks for the link. I have heard about it before and will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`ViewBag` is a property of `ControllerBase`, which all controllers must inherit from. It's a `dynamic` object, that's why you can add new properties to it without getting compile time errors.

It's not `static`, it's a member of the object. During the request lifetime, the controller instance is created and disposed, so you won't have "concurrency" problems, like overwriting the value.

The `View` (and its variants) method is not `static` as well, and this is how the view receives the `ViewBag` values: during the process of rendering the view, the controller instance has its ViewBag instance as well.

Comment: `ViewBag` is a property of `WebViewPage` as well. how does it get data which is assigned to `ControllerBase.ViewBag` property. Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: @Abi the view receives it from the controller when the `ActionResult` is being created. If we take ASP.NET Core MVC as an example, you can see that `ViewContext` receives it on the ctor: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/ViewContext.cs

Answer (score 12):

If you would analyse [ControllerBase](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerBase.cs) class you would see that ViewBag property is a "proxy" to ViewData property just to make your source look nicer. (I even remember Scott Hanselman taking interview from Phil Haack where Phil introduced ViewBag property as a shortcut to ViewData and eliminating the need of repeated square brackets and quotes). Even though `ViewBag` property is exposed as `dynamic` object it implements a [DynamicViewDataDictionary](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DynamicViewDataDictionary.cs) class which works directly with ViewData.

Looking at source code of [Controller](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs) class you can find this method:

```
protected internal virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
```

So basically when you call `return View();` from your controller it creates a new instance of `ActionResult` class passing ViewData from controller to it's constructor. Instance of `ActionResult` is then passed to a particular view engine (ASPX, Razor) so it could be used to render a view in question.

Making ViewBag/ViewData public static could be harmful. Each web request to your MVC application creates a new instance of controller. If you'd have ViewData/ViewBag as public static then two concurrent users would share same data from ViewBag/ViewData.

[Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/HanselminutesOn9/Hanselminutes-on-9-ASPNET-MVC-3-and-NEW-ASPNET-Futures-with-Phil-Haack-and-Morgan-the-Intern) is a video. Discussion on ViewBag (formder ViewModel) starts at 04:05

Answer (score 6):

[`ViewBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) is a property of [`ControllerBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492869%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).  It is defined as follows:

```
public Object ViewBag { get; }
```

Note that this signature is actually incorrect.  Here's what the source code actually looks like:

```
public dynamic ViewBag {
        get {
            if (_dynamicViewDataDictionary == null) {
                _dynamicViewDataDictionary = new DynamicViewDataDictionary(() => ViewData);
            }
            return _dynamicViewDataDictionary;
        }
    }
```

`_dynamicViewDataDictionary` is an ExpandoObject; you can add properties to it at runtime.  Its lifetime is the same as that of the controller, which is the lifetime of the HTTP request.

Comment: It appears the ViewBag property of ControllerBase has been consistently defined as dynamic, perhaps recently: `public dynamic ViewBag { get; }`

Comment: ViewBag is a property of WebViewPage as well. how does it get data which is assigned to ControllerBase.ViewBag property. Can you elaborate please ?