# is there a way that I can pass just an integer to my view without creating a model in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller which calls a view. Is there a way I can pass just an integer to my view an be able to use that integer in my view with razor code?

Here is my method in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int linkableId)
{
    return View(linkableId);
}
```

After returning my view, can I access just this int using razor code like this or something:

```
@linkableId
```

Comment: Use the dynamic collection `ViewBag` In the controller: `ViewBag.linkableId = 123123` in the view: `@ViewBag.linkableId`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your View, at the very top:

```
@model Int32
```

Or you can use a ViewBag.

```
ViewBag.LinkableId = intval;
```

Comment: My preference is I tend to go for the `ViewBag` approach when there is only one property passed into the view that does not need a viewmodel. Like in the example above this allows the view to be more readable, meaning I can see what @model really is without tracing it back to the controller to see it's a LinkableId in this example.

Answer (score 11):

Use `ViewBag`.

```
public ActionResult Details(int linkableId)
{
    ViewBag.LinkableId = linkableId;
    return View();
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@ViewBag.LinkableId
```

This question may also help: 
[How ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896013/how-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc-works)

Comment: I've never been a fan of Viewbags because they're just black holes you can put anything into.  But they are so very easy to use.

Answer (score 7):

In your View, at the very top:

```
@model Int32
```

then use this in your view, should work no problem.For example:

```
<h1>@Model</h1>
```

Something else that I want to add is is your controller you should say something like this :

```
return View(AnIntVariable);
```