# How to get parameters of action of controller from view post

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller action in `asp.net mvc` application

```
 public ActionResult ForFahrzeug(DateTime? initDate = null, DateTime? finalDate = null, long id = 0, long days = 0, string ExpGnr = "")
    {
        //body
    }
```

I am calling this above method in a view as below

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ForFahrzeug", "Messungen", FormMethod.Get))
{     

      <P>Fahrten von:
      @Html.TextBox("initDate", "", new { style = "width:15%", @class = "datefield" })  bis: 
      @Html.TextBox("finalDate", "", new { style = "width:15%", @class = "datefield" }) 

     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> </p> 
}
```

I want to get the value of "ExpGnr" from view. How could I do it? I tried to do it like below but it does not work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForFahrzeug", "Messungen", FormMethod.Get, new { ExpGnr = "Smart_ED"}))
{     
     Fahrten von:
      @Html.TextBox("initDate", "", new { style = "width:15%", @class = "datefield" })  bis: 
      @Html.TextBox("finalDate", "", new { style = "width:15%", @class = "datefield" }) 

     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> </p> 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understand your problem. Seems like you choose incorrect overload of method @Html.BeginForm(). 
You should write something like that:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForFahrzeug", "Messungen", new { ExpGnr = "Smart_ED"},FormMethod.Get))
```

Always choose correct [overload of MVC extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) OR use VisualStudio help messages for it.

And look,is any important reason why you submit your form through GET method? In most cases form should be submitted using POST request.

And, i suppose you need use some ViewModel for you Form. ViewModel-based Solution is be more clear, extensible and traditionally for MVC).
You also can add ExpGnr property in ViewModel and pass it to controller through `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ExpGnr)` 
Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) topic will be useful for you.

**Update**

Ok. this will work:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForFahrzeug", "Messungen", FormMethod.Get))
{     
      @Html.Hidden("ExpGnr","Smart_ED")
      @Html.TextBox("initDate", "", new { style = "width:15%", @class = "datefield" })
      @Html.TextBox("finalDate", "", new { style = "width:15%", @class = "datefield" }) 
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> 
}
```

Thank you)

Comment: the beginform method you suggested does not work I have already tried this.

Comment: @wafeeq, Ok. You can use Hidden field, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you wanna pass some data from action to view. You should use [ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896013/how-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc-works) for this purpose.

Comment: I want to pass data from view to action.