# ViewBag object in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic, properties, viewbag

I am learning MVC and I was going through articles on `ViewBag` object. Every article mentions that its a dynamic property. But I would like to know what actually is a dynamic property and why and when should we use it?

I would like to know an example of dynamic property as I am a beginner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the 'dynamic' type in C# 4.0 used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690623/what-is-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0-used-for)

Comment: try this [Answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896013/how-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc-works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896013/how-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc-works)