# How to apply CSS to Html.ValidationSummary at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am building my first MVC4 website and I would like to show success message when page successfully submitted. I have achieved by using     `ModelState.AddModelError(("", "Data successfully saved.");` but it is showing in the red color. I want to apply different css at runtime based on some conditions.

Thanks.

Comment: ping the set of code.. where u r using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when the result of an action method is successful a redirect happens, maybe that's what you want, especially if your result is not a json result. But if you are returning the same view after your post then you are doing it incorrectly. If the `ModelState` is valid on a post, that is if the validation passed (e.g. required fields are supplied), and you add an error message by doing `ModelState.AddModelError(("", "Data successfully saved.")` then you are making the `ModelState` go into an invalid state. That is the reason why you have the red color.

Now assuming you really want to return the same view then I suppose you have something like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourActionMethod(YourModel model)
    {          
        // some code goes here

        ModelState.AddModelError(("", "Data successfully saved.")
        return View(", model);
    }
```

What you should have instead is something like this:

```
        [HttpPost]        
        public ActionResult YourActionMethod(YourModel model)
        {          
            // some code goes here

            ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Data successfully saved.";
            return View(", model);
        }
```

Then on your view something like:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.SuccessMessage)) {
            <div class="success-summary">
                <p>@ViewBag.SuccessMessage</p>
            </div>    
}
```

Note that you don't need an additional `@` before the if, that code assumes it's inside a `form` tag, using `@using`. And then for the css:

```
.success-summary {
    color: #3366FF;
}
```

You can actually use either ViewData or ViewBag. To know more about the difference of the two you can [visit this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705426/whats-the-difference-between-viewdata-and-viewbag).

**UPDATE:**

```
[HttpPost]        
            public ActionResult YourActionMethod(YourModel model)
            {          
                //
                If (ModelState.IsValid) {
                                @ViewBag.IsModelValid = true;
                                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data successfully saved."); 
                                return View(model);  
                }

                ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Data successfully saved.";
                return View(", model);
            }
```

Your view:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class= (ViewBag.IsModelValid!=null && ViewBag.IsModelValid) ? "success-summary" : "" })
```

Comment: I know what you are trying to explain. I think you have not understood my query or I have not explained it so well. Any way thanks for your efforts. I'll try one more time to explain the issue:

Let us take an example of the Default Account control generated with the MVC4 Internet template:
this is the login method to login:

Comment: Detail
[IMG]http://i45.tinypic.com/b6stiv.png[/IMG]
http://i45.tinypic.com/b6stiv.png

Comment: If you read my answer again you will notice that you need to insert the ViewBag code inside the `if (ModelState.IsValid...`, then do the rest of my suggestion.

Comment: I have read your answer and I already know this approach, I this approach I have to maintain 1) @viewbag div and 2) ValidationSummary. So why we cannot use single ValidationSummary to show error and success messages. I you are not aware we can show informational messages in validationsummary. I just not getting the method to add dynamic CSS to validationsummary according to conditions.

Comment: Be assured I know all what you are talking about too ;) Are you aware you can approach your problem as per my suggestion and you can do it another way too? I prefer to have it separate so the ValidationSummary shows errors and completely have a different element to show a success message. If you know how to use a ViewBag as you've mentioned then you can use it to indicate the success of the post and change the css accordingly. I'll try to update my answer to suit your **preference**.

Comment: Thanks von v for your efforts. Kindly get back if you found any solution.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using TempData instead of changing validationsummary and @von described it very well.  Use bootstrap.  You could do something like this:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ManageUsers(UserViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User obj = new User();
            obj.UserName = model.Email;
            obj.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            obj.LastName = model.LastName;
            obj.Email = model.Email;
            obj.Phone = model.Phone;
            obj.Notes = model.Notes;
            obj.Authorized = model.Authorized;
            UserRepository.SaveUser(obj);
            TempData["Success"] = "Yes";
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
@if (TempData["Success"] != null)
{
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                    <strong>Success!</strong> The User account was created.
                </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Von, I too appreciate your answer, but I agree with MaxPayne that you didn't quite provide an answer for the question, more of a work around IMO. 
I too am looking at a way to style the ValidationSummary without the extra baggage of using the ViewBag.

I do agree that you shouldn't return to the same view after a post unless there are errors, but I do believe there are times when one might want to change the ValidationSummary style dynamically without having to use the ViewBag.

So far this is my only lead http://westcountrydeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/mvc-validation-part-4-styling-the-validation-controls/

I suppose you could use some JQuery to change the element's css attributes based on the Validation response.

```
var valid = $("#formID").validate().element("#ElementID");
//or
var valid = $('#formID').validate();
// Then use $(".ElementClass").css({}); to change the the style
```