# Attach common properties to all views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've implemented authorizationfilter to check if user access to the view. Along with that there is readonly attribute that needs to be attached to the view in the application.

Is context.Items only way to store the readonly property in authorization filter to retrieve it in controller.

Comment: OK, I'm confused.  You want to access it in the view or the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using at least MVC3, then you can use `ViewBag`:

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.MyVariable = "some data";
```

Comment: can he use filterContext.Controller.ViewData["MyVariable"] = "data"; for mvc2?

Comment: Nope, `ViewBag` was added in MVC3.

Comment: I thought ViewBag  is just a dynamic wrapper around ViewData. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure wheter `ViewBag` is *just* a dynamic wrapper around `ViewData`, but it could be used for the same purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705426/whats-the-difference-between-viewdata-and-viewbag

Answer (score 2):

To access a property in all views, you can inherit from a [WebViewPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and reference that in the view web.config.

To access a property in all controllers, build a base controller with the logic you want and inherit the base in all your application controllers.