# How to view ViewBag content while debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

A very basic question: how can I easily view the contents of a ViewBag while debugging ASP.NET MVC controllers in Visual Studio?

As a workaround, I use temporary variables:

`string tmp = ViewBag.MyData;`

So, the problem is that viewing `ViewBag.MyData` directly is difficult, `tmp` is easy.

Comment: Did you try adding it as a watch expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To view the contents of ViewBag when debugging:

- At a breakpoint...
- Open (Debug menu / QuickWatch) and type in ViewBag.
- Click the arrows at the left-hand-side for ViewBag, then for Dynamic.
- The contents of ViewBag will be displayed.

[image]

Comment: Peek the value, thus my favourite.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily add `ViewBag` to Watcher. Then expand `Dynamic View` to see all properties.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using "View Models", for example:

**ViewModel**

```
public class HomeViewModel {
    public string Text { get; set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var viewModel = new HomeViewModel {
         Text = "My Text"
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyApplication.ViewModels.HomeViewModel

This is my text: @Model.Text
```

Comment: I highly recommend using a viewmodel too.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing the point here - But can you not simply put a break-point on the ViewBag property you want to view?

Click your `ViewBag.MyData` and hit <kbd>F9</kbd>. When debugging, once the break-point is hit, hover your mouse over the `ViewBag` to see its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can view `ViewData` instead. Each key in `ViewData` dictionary is a same property of `ViewBag`

[What's the difference between ViewData and ViewBag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705426/whats-the-difference-between-viewdata-and-viewbag)