# How to access properties in the model passed to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, abstract-data-type

I'm sending the following model to my view.

```
return View(new { url = returnUrl });
```

In the view, I'm don't want to specify any particular class for my object (since I wish to keep it flexible and elastic for now). So, the *@Model* is the apparently an object and as such, it's got no *url* property. Hence the error.

> Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'url'

Now, I do know that the thing inside the object has *url* property. I have assigned it to it and I also see it when watching the variable as the exception's been thrown.

My question is how to access the field. Is my only option declaring a class and type the model using *@model Something*? I can't use *as* keyword to type it to *var*...

In "plain" C# we can do something like this.

```
var some = new {thing = "poof"};
string output = some.thing;
```

How do I do the equivalent of it in CSHTML file under Razor?

Comment: You should figure out what you want to display on there, and create a class with a `Url` property on it, and add as you need to expand.

Comment: Why not just use `ViewBag`?

Comment: @krillgar I know how to solve that **if** I introduce a new class. However, the point of the question is to resolve it **without** it. Please view the added example from "plain" C#. I'm curious how to enforce that in CSHTML. Alternatively, I'd like to know **why** it isn't possible.

Comment: @PaulAbbott That's a feasible work-around (and I prefer that to declaring a custom class, at this point). Still, I'm curious why I can't use the usual C# syntax in the CSHTML page. Any ideas?

Comment: Your "plain c#' example is creating an anonymous type.  Anonymous types cannot be used outside of the scope they are declared in (which is your case is the controller action).  http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-anonymous-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strongly-typed view models are the way to go. Create a type that suits the needs of the view and treat reusability/duplication as a secondary concern.

However, let me explain why your attempt did not work.

It is legal to pass an anonymous type--even between assemblies<sup>[1]</sup>--as long as it is cast to `object`. In fact, the MVC framework assemblies consume anonymous types in many helper methods. Those anonymous types are then evaluated using reflection (optimized by caching).

<sup>1: I believe there are some caveats to this, and it certainly isn't good practice in most cases.</sup>

A view is compiled into a class so that it can be executed. Part of the class's contract is the type of model it expects, as indicated by `@model` in your view markup.

This presents a problem with anonymous types, as you cannot indicate their type in your view and type `object` doesn't expose the properties you set when declaring the type. Thus, you end up with a view that only knows that its model is an object.

**Again, use strongly-typed models**, or the ViewBag if you truly only need one or two values.

However, to prove that the anonymous type *can* be passed to the view, look at this (horrible) example:

**Controller**

```
return View( new { property1 = "hello world"} );
```

**View**

```
@model object
@{
    var rvd = new RouteValueDictionary( Model );
}

@rvd["property1"]
```

We passed an anonymous type to the view as an object, and then read the object's properties using `RouteValueDictionary`.

Comment: 1. Truly a horrible example (I appreciate the fact that you actually present it to prove the case but won't be using it, of course). 2. How does that relate to the *dynamic* keyword (should it be avoided or can it be recommended - I've never had the need nor opportunity to apply it so it'd be interesting)? 3. Is *ViewBag* preferred before *ViewData* (I've seen both but people generally tend to suggest the former or both but never the latter alone)?

Comment: 2) `dynamic` is designed for cases where you cannot easily know the type information at compile time (or just don't want to specify type information). It's different than an anonymous type, which *is* strongly-typed at compile time, just not in an easily-consumable way. 3) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705426/whats-the-difference-between-viewdata-and-viewbag. The fact that `ViewBag` uses `dynamic` shows that it is not completely discouraged. Personally I've gotten used to creating many, purpose-specific view models (which was a paradigm shift for me).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ViewData` and `ViewBag` to send objects to the view page, in your case you can write in the controller something like this:

```
ViewData["url"] = url ; //Or whatever 
return View();
```

Now in the view you can simply use your object example:`<div>@ViewData["url"]</div>`

But mainly in **MVC** it is more recommended to use **strongly typed** **View Models**

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using the **dynamic** type in C#.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx for details.

While the standard would be to use a strongly-typed view model, there are some scenarios where you might want to use **dynamic** as your model type (or as a property of your strongly-typed view model), such as in a CMS where the properties are built dynamically by the CMS Provider.

Example view:

```
@model dynamic
<p>
    Url:  @Model.url
</p>
```